# Shadow DOM "debug" working for Firefox but minified version is not?

Tags: dart, angular-dart

http://pub.dartlang.org/packages/shadow_dom

Including the debug version works for me in Firefox, but the minified version does not. Is there any reason I shouldn't use the debug version in production? I don't seem to have much of a choice at the moment.

Has anyone else encountered this?

I'm using angular.dart if it matters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a known issue. Track here:

https://github.com/Polymer/ShadowDOM/issues/372

https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=16529

Comment: Thanks much. Know if anything bad will happen if using debug in "production" ?

Comment: Debug version is bigger, and possibly a little bit slower. Let us know how it turns out. :)